# Sync datastream to AWS S3 with Apache flink

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink

I want to know how to sync datastream to AWS S3 with apache flink(1.0-snapshot) without hadoop.
Every stream has its own filename, so I think it needs `OutputFormat`.
However I cannot find any example or article.

Answer (score 0):

create core-site.xml
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html

```
~.addSink(info => {
        val textOutputFormat = new TextOutputFormat[String](new Path("s3://${bucketname}/${file.path}"))
        val configuration = new Configuration()
        // ... config ...
        textOutputFormat.configure(configuration)
        textOutputFormat.open( ... ... )
        textOutputFormat.writeRecord( ... )
        textOutputFormat.close() // must do or not upload tempfile to s3
    })
```